# Display changing without AJAX

Tags: php, javascript

I have 2 drop down lists , and value of the second drop down list should change according to the value selected in first drop down list. The current drop down lists are.

```
<select name="first">
        <option name="a" value="a">a</option>
        <option name="b" value="b">b</option>
        <option name="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>

<select name="second">
       <option name="a1" value="a1">a1</option>
       <option name="a2" value="a2">a2</option>
       <option name="b1" value="b1">b1</option>
       <option name="b2" value="b2">b2</option>
       <option name="c1" value="c1">c1</option>
       <option name="c2" value="c2">c2</option>
</select>
```

I want the second drop down to be displayed according to the value selected in First dropdown, ie, if "a" is selected in first then only a1 and a2 should be shown. Also drop down values are pulled from a database
Thanks

Comment: Without AJAX (specifically JavaScript) you're limited to a POST/page refresh.

Comment: There is no need for AJAX at all: remember, AJAX means that you are doing (asynchronously) a REQUEST to a server to get your information. There is really no need to specifically exclude that as there isn't a reason to use it: your values come from the page itself. Maybe you mean something else? Like 'no javascript' for instance? (which will be quite hard)

Comment: @kelly French : a simple jquery onchange is NOT AJAX. It is javascript, but has nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: can use javascript but without ajax

Comment: The only stipulation I see is no AJAX. Doesn't mean you can't dump every possible value and use (e.g.) css classes to make some visible based on previous `<select>`'s value.

Comment: @Brad there are plenty of values in dropdown more than 50

Comment: @Nanne - true but couldn't be sure if 'no AJAX' also meant no JavaScript.  With regular JavaScript it would be easy as long as the entire second list was known ahead of time. @look4php needs to clarify his restriction.

Comment: @look4php: Classic example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tk83D/ (I used jQuery for simplicity, but gives you the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to load everything you have in the database in a standard form such as JSON. Then, you'd have to write javascript to build the dropdowns dynamically as the user interacts with each item.

Here is an example of how you'd go about doing it http://jsfiddle.net/9Z5t8/1/

There are some drawbacks. If you have a LOT of data (hundreds of records) to transfer this will be slow, but it's okay for a few records.

Answer (score 1):

There are just limited options to do so

- OnChange event
- Classic html/javascript/post refresh

Comment: +1 for onChange - that's how I'd do it. No need to send any data to the server.

Comment: u mean to display all the values in 2nd dropdown and hide and display  on onchange? @Nightfirecat

Answer (score 0):

You can save the options in a separate array, and insert the appropriate ones when a value is selected: http://jsfiddle.net/KTQ7d/.

```
var arr = [];
var first_select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
var second_select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1]
var elems = second_select.getElementsByTagName('option');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    arr.push(elems[i].value);
}
first_select.onchange = function() {
    second_select.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i][0]
       ==
       first_select.options[first_select.selectedIndex].value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.name = arr[i];
        opt.value = arr[i];
        opt.innerHTML = arr[i];
        second_select.appendChild(opt);
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: thx plmvdb,  also can it be done if the 2 displayed drop downs are actually pulled from a tables in db

Comment: @look4php: I don't know your scenario, but as long as you have HTML like in your question, you can execute this code.

Comment: @look4php: I cannot understand you completely - you do not want to use JavaScript?